# upload array in mongoDB using express and node

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mern

I need to insert an array in mongoDB but an empty array is inserted all the time. What am I doing wrong?

My schema

```
const taskSchema = new Schema({
    username: { type: String, required: true },
    title: { type: String, required: true },
    subtasks: [String]                        //how to define array as type here?
}, {
    timestamps: true,
});
```

data to be updated:

```
{
    "username": "test",
    "title": "test",
    "subtasks": ["task1", "task2"]
}
```

Update: it works now.

I had an err in route file, I had "subtasksArray" instead of subtasks there:

```
const router = require('express').Router();
let TodaysTask = require('../models/todaysTask.model');

router.route('/add').post((req, res) => {
  const username = req.body.username;
  const title = req.body.title;
  const subTaskArray = req.body.subtasksArray;    //it should be subtasks here

  const newTodaysTask = new TodaysTask({
    username,
    title,
    subtasksArray      
  });

  newTodaysTask.save()
  .then(() => res.json('Task added!'))
  .catch(err => res.status(400).json('Error: ' + err));
});
```

Comment: Your code where you're trying to do the insert would be helpful. The schema definition looks fine.

Comment: Hi I am passing the data to be updated part of question through postman. Everything works fine but the subtasks is always empty ( [ ] ), it should b an array with task1 & task2, isn't it?

Comment: can you post more code relevant to the question? the function where you receive the HTTP method, and the method you use to persist the data.

Comment: thankyou it worked now. I had an error in the route file - used subtasksArray instead of subtasks.

Answer (score 1):

you defined the attribute `tasks` but are trying to insert `subtasks`.

Maybe define the attribute `subtasks`

Comment: I made a mistake in the question... sorry it is subtasks(both)...